# Random freezes on Ubuntu 18.04 on Lenovo Ideapad 330s with AMD A9

Tags: 18.04, amd-processor, ideapad

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 18.04(Kernel 4.15-29) on a Lenovo Ideapad 330s.

The system configurations are:

- AMD A9-9425(Integrated Radeon R5 graphics)
- 4GB RAM

The installation completed without any problem. And I was able to successfully login and use the system for a few hours. But after the 5th or 6th boot the system freezes a few seconds into the login screen. I tried reinstalling and the same thing kept happening.

I am not that used to using Ubuntu. So if somebody could help me with this problem it would be life saving (Bought the laptop just to run Ubuntu for work and can't even return it).

Comment: Black listing amdgpu has fixed the issue. But now I can't adjust the screen brightness

Comment: Did you try to use AMD GPU drivers from here : https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-20